# How to update the key and not the value in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a username collection like so :

[image]

This makes it easier to reference if  username is available or not when I sign up a user. I set the Username to the `uid` of the user that way I can reference which username belongs to who.

The way I create this was:

`firebase.database().ref('usernames').child(username).set(user.uid)`

Now I am trying to update a user's username but keep the uid the same, so the only thing that changes is the user's username and nothing else. I tried some different things with the `update()` but couldn't seem to use it correctly.

Comment: Why didn't you used `user_id` and than `username` and `password`? That way you'd simply modify `username` value - where `user_id` is *XY*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't update keys in Realtime Database.  The best you can do is delete the key and value, then re-add the value with the key that you want in place of the old one.

Comment: @TaylorAustin Please accept this answer as correct (unless you somehow found a way to update the key).

Comment: sorry it made me wait 8 minutes for some reason

Comment: Ah, yes, there is some rate limiting to combat automated abuse.